# Setting Visibility in OpenLayers?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, jquery

If the name of my layer in openlayers is "olayer". And if i want to set its visibility to true. Then the simple code is

```
    olayer.setVisibility(true);
```

But if i want to set the visibility by storing the layer's name in a different variable like this:

```
     var vari="olayer";        
     vari.setVisibility(true);
```

This won't work because its taking "vari" as the name of the layer instead of the string stored in variable "vari".

Comment: As you have written it, vari equals a string olayer, so the behaviour yoobservce is expected. If you want an object reference, then use, 'var vari = olayer;

Answer (score 2):

`"olayer"` is just a string instead of a reference. As such it does not provide a method called `SetVisibility`.

When you want to set `olayer`s properties (be aware that there are no quotes) or call its methods you have to use a reference to it:

```
var vari = olayer;
olayer.SetVisivility(true);
```

You can get a layer by name using [`getLayersByName`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getLayersByName).

From that you can call `SetVisibility`:

```
var layer = map.getLayersByName("olayer")[0];
layer.SetVisibility(true);
```

Comment: i mean can't i use a variable that stores the name of the layer for using setvisibility function? i.e if i use a variable it returns the name of the layer when calling a function.